# Scanner with Enum, Java

Tags: java, string, enums, java.util.scanner, value-of

I'm doing an assignment for uni and am stuck on litterelly one line of code.

```
public static void setKind(SettlementType type) {
        SettlementType t;
        t = scan.nextLine();
        setKind(t = type);
```

As you can see I am using a scanner to take in the the `SettlementType`, however, the IDE keeps saying that I need to change `SettlementType` to `String`. I'm new to Java and couldn't find a fix if anyone knows could you perhaps walk me through it?

Comment: Since `scan.nextLine()` returns a String, you can't assign it to an Enum.

Comment: It looks like XY problem to me. I see you're missing basics of how programming works(assignments, recursion, method/function invoking). Pleas rephrase your question to tell what you want to achieve. Code you posted is wrong beyond simple answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An each `enum` has `valueOf` method that turns `String` value into `enum` object.

```
SettlementType t = SettlementType.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
```

The `IllegalArgumentException` exception may be throw if the `enum` has no constant with the specified name.

Comment: Thank you java gure, you have helped a lot

Comment: This solves what exactly? I don't believe @mkirito that your code works like a charm just because you copy pasted this one line. Or does it?

Comment: @zubergu, why do you think that this code doesn't work?

Comment: @zubergu you are correct the code as a whole ddoesent work like a charm however this was the problem that needed to be soved at the given time so i could start solving every other problem within the code. basically i was unsure of how to get the scanner to work with Enums

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I'm not saying your piece of code won't work - I was just stating that this doesn't work with OPs code. As it turned out  - i was right, and now we'll see follow-up questions to the same problem some time soon. That's all.